# Where is the actions pane of the class library in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, interface-builder, xcode4.6, xcode4.6.3

I'm following along on this [tutorial](https://www.cocoalab.com/?q=node/14) with Xcode 4. The tutorial is for Xcode 3, with Interface Builder, and Xcode has changed since then.

The step I'm on:

[image: diagram of Xcode 3 step]
<sub>(source: [cocoalab.com](http://www.cocoalab.com/media/becomeanxcoder/08/20_class_library.png))</sub>

> In the palette, in the Action section, click the Add (+) button to add an action (i.e., an action method) to the MFAExampleClass class. Replace the default name provided by Interface Builder by a more meaningful name (for example, you can enter "setTo5:" because we will program this method to display the number 5 in the text field). Add another method, and give it a name (for example "reset:", because we will program it to display the number 0 in the text field). Note that our method names both end with a colon (":"). More about this later.

I've looked through menu items that could be what the "class library" pane, but I can't find it.
Does anyone know where it is? Or do I have to accomplish this in a different way then the tutorial describes?

Running Xcode `4.6.3`, on Mac OS X `10.8.4`.

Comment: Just add the method to the class interface and implementation manually. It should have the signature `-(IBAction)setTo5:(id)sender`.

Comment: @Kevin So I just type that into the interface and implementation, and I'm good?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to follow it with a `;`  in the interface and `{}` in the implementation (until you fill in the code there). If you scroll down a bit in the tutorial you'll see the code.

Comment: @Kevin: make that a answer and I'll accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That button just adds a stub method to your class. You can add it manually:

```
@interface MFAExampleClass : NSObject
...
-(IBAction)setTo5:(id)sender;
@end
```

and

```
@implementation MFAExampleClass
...
-(IBAction)setTo5:(id)sender
{
    // Action code here
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open up an assistant window fr the header file next to the nib, and opt-drag a button to create IBOutlet or IBAction